# Use of . in python?

Tags: python

I am struggling to explain the use of the dot. I thought it might be another way of multiplying variables but get an error when I try run such a code.

I can't explain what it is doing exactly, take this code for example:

```
import random

for i in range(100):
   value = random.randint(1, 10)
   print(value)
```

I understand what the code does but in line 3 I am confused by `random.randint` what is the dot doing here? `randint` is not defined or imported so how does the program know what is being asked of it?

An brief explanation of the above code would be nice but a good explanation of the use of the dot in python would be appreciated.

Comment: `random` is module and `randint()` is method, Dot used to access method from module. Can you write simple code of class? e.g. Addition of two number. then create object of that class and call addition method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use dot for 3 main reasons:

1. Accessing members of a module: a module is simply a python file, and members can be variables, functions, classes and so on.
2. Accessing modules within a package: a package is a directory containing a__init__ module. Some packages are nested and contain inner packages. You have to reach the innermost and then the module. For both you use dot syntax.
3. And at last, accessing members of a class, for example method (functions) fields (variables) and so on.

In your above code random is a Python module and you are accessing its function randint.

Answer (score 0):

`random` is a package and `randint()` is its method. Dot notation here works just like it does in any other language. It's used to access the 
`randint` property of `random` module.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, the dot operator is used to access attributes of objects.

In your example, think of the module imported "random" as an object which has various functions like randint, shuffle, etc

So, when you say "random.randint()", you are accessing the function "randint" from the module "random"

Answer (score 0):

The dot here is used to resolve scope. The `randint()` function is inside the `random` module. The dot here tells the interpreter where to look for the named function/ data member.

Apart from this, the dot is also used to access functions and data members from an object reference.
For example:

```
op = object.function()
```

Here, the `function()` is being accessed using the reference of `object`.

Also you can access inner modules using `.` like this:

```
import module.submodule
```

More information here: https://www.codecademy.com/en/forum_questions/5170307264a7402d9a0012f5

Comment: Thanks for all the explanations.

Comment: You're welcome. Do consider an upvote if you found it useful.

Comment: It is not an issue of scope. It is always attribute access.